# Log4j configuration for multiple logging design issue

Tags: spring, web-applications, log4j, spring-aop

I have to implement log4j in following manner in our web application:

1) DEBUG level logs must not append in any file. These logs should available only on console of development workstations/IDEs while developing the application. - its happening now but after deployment these logs get appended in catalina.out which I have to stop.

2) INFO  onward application logs should go in one log file - its happening right now.

3) One another file based logging should also happen for performance logging of entire application using Spring AOP - not yet implemented.

log4j configuration is given below:

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="true">
<appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender" >
<param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />   
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
     <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p  [%c{1}] %m %n" />
  </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
  <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
  <param name="File" value="${catalina.home}/logs/dashboard.log"/>
  <param name="DatePattern" value="'-'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'"/>
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
     <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%d{ISO8601}] - %-5p- [%X{USER_ENCRYPT_ID}%x] - %C.%M(%F:%L) - %m %n" />
  </layout>
</appender>


<logger name="com.project14" additivity="false" >   
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" /> 
  <appender-ref ref="fileAppender"/>      
</logger>

</log4j:configuration>
```

I am new for log4j configuration, so please validate and suggest necessary implementation to achieve my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want different appenders to push logs to different log files or something similar.

One thing you are missing here. Please try to use filters. Here is a simple example which sends different logs to different files using filters.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="true">
<appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p  [%c{1}] %m %n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="fileAppenderInfo" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
    <param name="File" value="d:/info.log" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'-'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
            value="[%d{ISO8601}] - %-5p- [%X{USER_ENCRYPT_ID}%x] - %C.%M(%F:%L) - %m %n" />
    </layout>
     <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
                    <param name="levelMin" value="INFO" />
                    <param name="levelMax" value="INFO" />
     </filter>
</appender>

<appender name="fileAppenderDebug" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
    <param name="File" value="d:/debug.log" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'-'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
            value="[%d{ISO8601}] - %-5p- [%X{USER_ENCRYPT_ID}%x] - %C.%M(%F:%L) - %m %n" />
    </layout>
     <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
                    <param name="levelMin" value="DEBUG" />
                    <param name="levelMax" value="DEBUG" />
     </filter>
</appender>

<appender name="fileAppenderWarn" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="Threshold" value="WARN" />
    <param name="File" value="d:/warn.log" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'-'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
            value="[%d{ISO8601}] - %-5p- [%X{USER_ENCRYPT_ID}%x] - %C.%M(%F:%L) - %m %n" />
    </layout>
     <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
                    <param name="levelMin" value="WARN" />
                    <param name="levelMax" value="WARN" />
     </filter>
</appender>


<logger name="com.log4j.test" additivity="false">
    <level value="all"/>
    <appender-ref ref="fileAppenderWarn" />
    <appender-ref ref="fileAppenderDebug"/>
    <appender-ref ref="fileAppenderInfo"/>
</logger>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Hope this helps. Please get back to me if you face some other issues.

Comment: Hey! Plz let me know, if this was your query and its the answer you were expecting

Comment: Thanks for response,It helps to filter out logs. But I don't want to log DEBUG level logs any where on server once application gets deployed in higher envs. Its useful in dev environment only. That's why my idea was to use console appender. Right now, as we deploy the app on test or production region it starts logging DEBUG level logs in catalina.out which is undesirable. One option is to remove DEBUG level entries from above config file before each iteration of deployment. But its not feasible every time. So any idea how to automate it?

Comment: Well, you do not want the log level DEBUG on your deployment server.. We achieve this by changing the server log level to anything above DEBUG. This is the actual way of achieving this.

Moreover, if you feel this solution is not feasible, you can configure log4j in a programmatic way where you can check the environment in the listener which initializes logger and create the appender for debug levels if it is development environment.